# how to parse namespace tag associated with unique value using python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have thousands of entries in a xml file which has a namespace name in each entry. A concise example I want to parse is as follows.

### A concise sample I want to parse

```
<d:entry d:title="Buddism" class="entry">
<span class="ps"> noun </span>
<span class="pinyin"> fojiao </span>
</d:entry>
<d:entry d:title="hew" class="entry">
<span class="ps"> verb </span>
<span class="pinyin"> jue </span>
</d:entry>
<d:entry d:title="roost" class="entry">
<span class="ps"> noun </span>
<span class="pinyin"> qixidi </span>
</d:entry>
```

### Heading

I try to parse it with BeautifulSoup4 with following steps, but nothing happen.

```
➜  ~  python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul 28 2016, 21:28:00)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> xmlstr = """
... <d:entry d:title="Buddism" class="entry"><span class="ps"> noun </span><span class="pinyin"> fojiao </span></d:entry><d:entry d:title="hew" class="entry"><span class="ps"> verb </span><span class="pinyin"> jue </span></d:entry><d:entry d:title="roost" class="entry"><span class="ps"> noun </span><span class="pinyin"> qixidi </span></d:entry>"""
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(xmlstr, "xml")
>>> t = soup.find(r'd:title="hew"')
>>> t
>>> t.ps
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ps'
>>> type(t)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

How to parse it within BeautifulSoup or the similar tools? I do not want to manually parse it with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(xmlstr, 'lxml')
soup.find(attrs={'d:title':'hew'}).find(class_='ps')
```

out:

```
<span class="ps"> verb </span>
```

1. First, I recommend use 'lxml'
2. Second, the thing you are find is
       atrribute, not a tag name, you can not do `soup.attrs`

Comment: Thank you very much. I finally know why 'class_' is used, because 'class' is a reserved keyword. I myself figure out a method that blow my mind. ```soup.find(**{'d:title':'hew'}).find(**{'class'='ps'})```